# "Prr"/Crackling/Popping subtle noise when playing any kind of audio only on windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, realtek-hd-audio

I recently bought a Lenovo Legion Y530-15ICH Type 81GT and everything seemed to works fine until recently when i noticed that everytime the speakers were playing anything (music or video) every now and then there would be a subtle "prr" noise (like a sort of that white noise you hear when connects your headphone to the p2) that lasts less than one second. While it is subtle, after youu notice it, it becomes REALLY annoying.

It randomly appears. I have used this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNf9nzvnd1k ) to check if it was more intense on one frequency than another, but it is not the case. If i play the video over and over the noise appears at different frenquencies. In fact, if I play a silent audio file, it still occurs.
Although it is random, it appears, on average, one time every 15 seconds.

The volume seems to interfere with it (not surprisingly). The higher the volume set on windows, the higher the noise.

It is not a speaker problem for two reasons:
1) When I connect the headphones the same thing happens on the headphones
2) I used a live session fedora to boot on my computer and played all kinds of audio there. Not a single noise was heard. It seems clear to me, by that, that it is a software issue.

I have tried all basic suggestions for windows audio problems:
a) Upgrading the audio driver
b) Downgrading the audio driver
c) Enabling and disabling any audio enhancement
d) Change the audio format on the speakers properties at control panel
e) Running windows troubleshoot for audio
f) Restarting the audio services

None of which worked.

I'm really out of ideas now. Does anyone knows at least one hint I could use to dig into this? I couldn't even find anyone on google with the same problem

I'm using an intel i5-8300H with Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050 (4GB). It came with a 1TB HDD and I have added a 500GB SSD NVMe from WD (SN500). Although I did not notice this problem before adding the SSD, it could be that it already happened and i was just not so aware of it.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
MAJOR PLOT TWIST

I still use Power Plans (power saving ; maximum perfomance) and noticed something very odd: on the "Maximum perfomance" plan, this problem would occur, however, not in the "Power Saving" mode. I'm trying to find out what configuration is causing this. First i thought it was definetively  the "Link state power managemenet" on PCI Express settings (specially after installing the SSD), but while they were indeed different on both plans, changing it didn't solve the problem. My second guess was the "Minimum processor state" on "Processor power management". On power saving mode, it was 5%, and on maximum perfomance it was 100%. But again, changing it did not solve the problem.
I notice that it also disappears on the Balanced power plan so I guess I'll just use it for now. It is a half-solution tho

Comment: Can you still hear it if you disable bluetooth and/or wireless adapter?

Comment: Got into airplane mode to check and still happened